# German correspondent for “cock wagon”

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

Both my parents were born in Germany and came to the US, when they were five years old. They spoke German to each other but not with us kids.

Now, I got my first job out of school and bought a Porsche.
My father called it a *cock wagon.* While this term is sometimes used in English (see [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cock+wagon) and [here](http://www.definition-of.com/cock-wagon)), I do not think that he meant this but rather was translating a German word.

What word could this be?

Comment: It seems to me that you want to know if there is a corresponding German expression to the English expression "cock wagon" that your father used. If it is not relevant to the question that his first language is German, then please delete that part. If you think that it is relevant, then please detail how so.

Comment: Wenn der Ausdruck bedeutet was ich meine, dann halte ich die Frage für begründet, als sich eine Übersetzung schlecht in Wörterbüchern finden lassen könnte. Geprüft habe ich das freilich nicht. Reopen! Carsten S' Anforderung, die Frage nicht unnötig durch Rauschen zu begleiten schließe ich mich jedoch an.

Comment: I edited your question and took some guesses as to what you are asking. Please check whether everything is still according to your intentions.

Comment: It's time that we can upvote edits. +1 for @Wrzlprmft. ;)

Comment: "Kill Bill" - I think Buck is driving a "pussy wagon", and pays for it with his life. But then he has the bad habit of raping women who are in his hospital in a coma, so it's quite deserved...

Answer (score 11):

I think what your father was getting at was the German word *Schwanzersatz*, *penis substitute*. It is a fairly common expression of envy to suggest that someone with a Porsche has a small penis, and tries to compensate with a fast/flashy car, to attract women, of course.

A different term used in a similar way would be *Aufreißerwagen*, where *aufreißen* means to catch the attention of someone, in a romantic or sexual way.

Comment: While *Schwanzersatz* certainly conveys the idea, it is applicable for other gadgets, too (like cutting-edge cell phones). A term with a narrower focus would be *Potenzhobel* (*virility plow*) that only applies to cars.

Comment: @collapsar: Hast Du schon "Schwanzersatz" oder "Penisverlängerung" für Iphone gehört?

Comment: @userunknown Nein, aber für die Top-Handys der Baureihen Nokia 20xx/27xx (iirc) und Motorola Razr. Für iPhones erwarte ich auch nicht, Schwanzersatz zu hören, denn dafür sind sie zu verbreitet.

Comment: *aufreißen* might also mean *angeben* "gloat, boast" (cp. *einen Aufriss machen* ca. "make a fuzz", "big fudge", not to be confused with *Aufrisszeichnung* "sketch, plan" (whence *sketchy*?)). I think your allusion of *cock car* to the male member is interesting, cocky, but somewhat misleading and ultimately *[ha(h)nebüchend](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanebüchen)* It could be spot-on for the intention in question, though.

Comment: @vectory: As far as I can tell, "aufreißen" cannot beunstood as "to gloat, to boast". It either has a literal meaning of "to tear something open", or it is a synonym to "anbaggern".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ja super, ein Slangwort durch das andere zu erklären verlagert nur das Problem. Natürlich denkt jedes Kind bei *anbaggern* zuerst an schweres Gerät. Das nächste Synonym, *angraben*, fördert das sicherlich, doch sind diese Synonyme etymologisch undurchsichtig und wie *begreifen* womöglich nicht zu den Grundbegriffen der deutschen Sprache zu stellen. Außerdem ist deine Aussage meines Wissens nicht richtig...

Comment: ... I don't think *anbaggern* were synonym to *aufreißen*, as the words are used in congruence with the prefixed adverbials. *an-* implies an ad-proach, ad-tempt, cp. *anbahnen, anbieten, buhlen, anbiedern, anbandeln*, maybe *angeben* (to brag, so, '\*anba(r)gan'? cp. metathesis in LG *burn* ~ HG *Brunnen*). Brrrr

Comment: ... whereas *aufreißen* implies success, essentially, that *anbaggern* does not, which is more notable in the partizip, *aufgerissen*, which only applies if the attempt worked *out*. PS: What counts as success it is of course entirely relative to one's expectations, but there's a clear contrast to *ab-blitzen*, *Abfuhr erhalten*, *ab-ge-wiesen werden* and the like. PPS: Have I just concured with @Takkat's answer, inadvertently? :)

Comment: I have never heard *Schwanzersatz*, but *Schwanzverlängerung* (*-verlängerung* meaning *extension*, or here *enlargement*). I think figuratively *-ersatz* makes less sense than *-verlängerung* because the notion behind this is that owners of those cars have some kind of inferiority complex they want to compensate, as opposed to 'replacing' anything.

Comment: @vectory: Es stimmt, das hatte ich nicht weit genug durchdacht. Ich ziehe die Aussage mit dem Synonym für "anbaggern" zurück; was ich zum Ausdruck bringen wollte, war, dass mir "aufreißen" für sich genommen, abgesehen von der wörtlichen Bedeutung, nur in der auf romantische Kontakte bezogenen Bedeutung geläufig ist.

Comment: @vectory 'aufreißen might also mean angeben "gloat, boast"' - Not in my corner of the world. I have never heard it used this way in Vienna. There's a similar word, "aufschneiden", which is used this way (though it's a bit archaic, and mostly used in its noun form "Aufschneider", to mean a braggard).

Comment: @Sebastian, right, *don't get cocky*, I am still missing the proverbial forrest for the trees, for the trees are levled.

Answer (score 4):

There is no similar sounding German expression that would fit to the context your father gave.

Sometimes we refer to over-designed sports cars owned by a certain male population as *Potenzschlitten* in colloquial slang. This may come close to the English term.

A better accepted not so rude term would be **Angeberauto**:

> Die futuristische Version vom Angeberauto: ein Lamborghini Aventador Roadster.<sup>[Focus](http://www.focus.de/fotos/die-futuristische-version-vom-angeberauto-ein-lamborghini-aventador_mid_1232179.html)</sup>
>   4er BMW: Angeberauto<sup>[faz](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/technik-motor/4er-bmw-angeberauto-13165920.html)</sup>

Comment: "There is no similar sounding German expression that would fit to the context your father gave." Vielleicht doch ... vgl. meine Antwort.

Comment: I would say "Angeberwagen". But that's just me.

Comment: @gnasher729: that's possible too (probably a [regional thing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Angeberwagen%2CAngeberauto&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3))

Answer (score 4):

"Schwanzverlängerung".

This translates to "cock extension" and is one of the more commonly heard phrases to convey what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative theory. The word "wagon" certainly stands for *car* - but why did your father use this word to denote a car and didn't simply say "cock car"?

I believe he was shocked when he saw your Porsche and used the German word "Kackwagen" (= crap car) because he didn't like Porsches or the car was almost scrap (*I got my first job out of school and bought a Porsche*). And you, not knowing German, understood "cock wagon". Yeah, somewhat speculative ...

But in fact the word "Kack" is frequently used as a prefix assigning a strongly negative connotation to the word which follows.

Examples:

[1.](https://www.verenas-welt.com/frau-stuermer-geht-es-so-wie-uns-allen/)  Hier treffen sich nur Kack-Bands und singen sich gegenseitig ihre Kack-Songs.

[2.](https://www.borussen.net/forum/forum.php/img/img/forum_entry.php?id=977958) Der kack Freistoß war sowas von unnötig.

[This source](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=kackdreist&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&sp0=rart_ou&sp1=rart_varianten_ou) says that it is mainly used in the Ruhr area and in Northern Germany.

Comment: Although this is somewhat correct, I'd say the usage is infrequent and maybe more frequent in certain collocations. *Kack wagen* is to my knowledge not so collocated, but google finds various results and, for reference, five for "kack angeber" as well (many more for "alter angeber", which is highly idiomatic; "scheiß" would surely trump any of those). Anyway, cock wagon has plenty results, even in g-books back to the 1800s at least, so pops certainly did not make it up.

Answer (score 1):

May be you would better not have been asking. I can tell you the answer if you don’t be afraid to hear it.

(Probably you won’t  drive your Porsche again without becoming blush for shame and you might think about of  rather selling it. But not to me.)

We have a perfect term that names it well and brings the things to the point!

**When we are overtaken on driving by a porsche and he speeds off my wife uses to say to me:**

*”E lueg doch mal, das Schnäbi!”* (Hey, look at this pretty little cock)

(Whereby Schnäbi means in German “Schnäbelein” or better “Schnäbelchen” which is the diminutive of “Schnabel” and names the little pecker of a boy! The pecker ...of which is to say: the pecker is the opposite end of a cock, as if the tail of a cock is -let’s say the left end, that’s also called cock, then the pecker is the right end of a cock, what doesn’t mean that a cock has two cocks! Perhaps “pecker” is a little too big to translate “Schnäbelein”, as this might rather fit for a wren, let’s say a speckle-breasted wren, or a black-bellied wren, or may be better a bar-winged wood-wren, or even better a chestnut-banded wren, no: a happy wren! That’s it! Perhaps you prefer to look up yourself all the wrens and decide which one might fit as the best. And don’t forget to spelling the latin names as there are pheugopedius
sclateri, thyrothorus fasciathoventris, henicorhina  leucoptera etcetera,etcetera ... you have to learn them all by heart!

https://www.dict.cc/?s=Zaunk%C3%B6nig

Mind: Most important is, it has to be a very, very little bird! The most pretty little bird of all!)

But when my wife gets really very, very angry and upset about an overtaking porsche driver she is insulting and offending: “So-ne Gigu!”

(what means exactly what you are looking for!)

And now I need a cock-tail!

I think I have to stop now ere they are going to on hold my answer -  calling me an “Unhold”!

Comment: Der Gimpel hat den kleinsten.

Comment: I didn't know that *Schnäbi* meant, let's say, "penis" in dialect. Are you just guessing? *Schnabel* chiefly means "bill, beak" (which *snaps*?). *pecker* is a neat allusion,  but I'm inclined to believe that your proposition is common because I know *Schniepel* ca. "nipple, snippit, lip [e.g of a tetra-pack]" but definitely "penis". Your allusion to tail feathers is confusing, but understandable comparing *pencil, penis, feather* etc. Now what about *Schnaps, cock-tail*? Does someone have something on *Rot-Schwanz, Fink, wing, Schwinge*?

Comment: no, I'm not guessing.That's the first word that a child learns after mama and papa!
https://www.srf.ch/kultur/film-serien/trigger-kurzfilm-der-woche/wer-hat-den-laengsten-schnaebi

http://www.voltafilm.ch/de/film/schn%C3%A4bi/video

that's definitely the expression for the penis and has no negative meaning for a little boy, but when calling adults like this it's a blaming

Comment: Remembered your answer when I saw [शिश्न](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/शिश्न#Sanskrit) (śiśna "penis")--Maybe related to Schnäbli? The *si-* could be explained as childish reduplication as in *Pipi, Mama*, etc. The missing "-bel, -bli" would be harder to explain. Synonymous Hindi बुल्ला (bullā) comes to mind, along with Lt. *phallus* (also Ger. *Pulla*, Romanian *pula*?); and *bill* (beak)? Analogous, *Bock* in "kein Bock" could be from Sanskrit "hunger", through Romani and Rothwelsch; well it seems fantastic. Speculated as source for an Albanian term. The root might mean "to pierce".

Comment: I'd consider the roots PIE \*swen- "power, might" (\*swent?) and \*bhel-~\*bhle- or \*bhu- "blow, swell". But I really don't know enough to substantiate that claim.

Comment: You may be right. This is not too far thinking: as many nouns for the objects around men seem to be derived of parts of the human body by similarity of shape, color and function as Kopf, cap, Nase, nes, Fuss, feet, Rücken, Herz,Hand, Finger, Zahn, Schulter... especially to describe the shape of the landscape: Felskopf, Bergnase, or the coast, Meeresbusen, Bergpüppi, Flussarm, Knie etc.  all these examples are obvious and don‘t need any improvement. It won‘t be speculated or fantastic to find analogous nouns and descriptions for things in our surroundings derived of the primary sexual organs.

Comment: Swen and Schwan, that‘s interesting. Anyway, we can be sure that such phenomens must have been quite impressing to early mankind and will have played an important role when men developed language, speaking and vocabulary.

Answer (score -2):

It might of interest to you that **cock-boat** exists as proper word, "a type of small boat" (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cock#Etymology_4). And it appears to be unrelated to the bird or the male member, although either etymology is not fully explained inasmuch as "child-talk"  and "onomatopoetic" are short hand for *the devil knows what they were thinking*. Although it is obvious that the distant etymology plays hardly any role in the translation, it is likewise obvious that nobody can really say what your senior intends to say. I mean, it was not a vulgar insult challenging you to a cock fight.

So, in defense of your Dad and the English language at large, one may assume that the word is in use with wide ranging connotations. Describing these would have been your responsibility, or a matter for english.stackexchange.That's the rules.

You can't translate *Blumenkohl* nilly willy as '* flower coal': it's *cauliflower*. Hence I suggest it was wrong from previous answears to jump to conclusions. Cock - *hahaha* - may be a dirty word in some limited contexts, but that's not enough to translate *cock-wagon* as *Penisprothese*, "Schwanzersatz", "Schnäbli", "Schwanzverlängerung", "Potenzschlitten", even "Aufreißerwagen" (*up-rip'er wagon*, literally *hook-up wagon*) or anything like that, although *Protzschlitten* would be a good translation for vanity brands like Porsche.

Rather, the perspective suggests itself: youth would typically get *small* cars, initially, and maybe they'd cock them - is this applicable to cars, *to arm up*, "To lift the cock of a firearm or crossbow" [en.wiktionary]; as for German cf. *auf-frisieren*),instead of *to tune*, *pimp*, etc.? Either way the young men would be happier than ever and potentially (ha!) brag about it.

Incidently, Porsche is known for the *Coupé* (cf. Fench "cut up", "shortened").

*protzig* suits insofar it is akin to *pretty*, from Proto-Germanic *prattugaz (“boastful, sly, slick, deceitful, tricky, cunning”). See similar French *petit*, akin to *petty* (ha!).

---

More over, the word's form and collocation invites comparison to *wheel* and its reconstructed root *kʷekʷl-, akin to Ancient Greek κύκλος (cf. *cycle*); see also: Spanish *chico* "young boy", Latin *ciccum* "proverbially worthless object, trifle, bagatelle", Ancient Greek κίκκος;  *chickpea*, Latin *cicer* "chickpea, (slang) testicle", Ancient Macedonian κίκερροι (kíkerrhoi, “chickpea”), etc. (supposed wanderword; cp. *peanuts* "little value", etc.). Although, this is not fully compatible with the boat sense, unless talking about a round boat, and a pathway for *cock* as borrowed from a comparable descendent from Proto-Indo-European *kʷékʷl-, which may also mean 'wagon' or 'chariot', seems to be unknown in the literature, I'd say it's a notable albeit unlikely avenue to pursue. Although *kʷekʷl- is the reduplication to *kʷel- "to turn", it would be necessary to assume here that the full grade was formed by analogy to the proper word.

---

In concusion, it's a matter of style. Translation practice offers enough freedome for a solution to interpret with a certain understatement

> hübsche kleine Karre

> nice little car

An all too literal translation instead would be *Gockel* + *Karre* (or *Wagen*, *Schlitten*, etc.), insofar as *stolzer Gockel* (proud cock) is a standing (ha!) collocation. But I doubt that this would be readily understood.

---

All this is pearls before the swines (Perlen vor die Säue) if the question was probably for one off use, for a homework in the worst case. If instead it was intended to settle an argument by reference to parallel constructions in other languages showing that it is vulgar, however, you may have to reconsider.